# How to see the 2024 Candidates Tournament

Tags: candidates

With the 2024 Candidates Tournament being in North America for the first time, I'm interested in seeing part of it if I can. However, searching online has yielded no results with details about getting tickets. Thus, how can tickets be purchased? Or is this a "by invitation" event?

Comment: The details about the tickets are not out yet. I'm hoping the details will be out soon, though. I suggest you keep checking the official website. That's where all the tickets and required details will be available.

Comment: You wont see tickets available to probably 2 months prior from my experience. Expect to pay about $150/day or probably $2k for a event pass which I generally do. Note the ticket prices may vary with who is selected as a candidate, eg; Abasov might have less pull than say Nakamura, who I would imagine would bring a lot more attention and draw more demand for tickets. Neither scenario is likely, so wouldn't stress too much. Ian or Fab would be the most likely to push through.

Comment: @Dheebs: Are you talking about the Candidates Tournament or the Championship Match? This question is about the Candidates Tournament, which will be in Toronto in April 2024, and where the participants will be Nepomniachtchi, Praggnanandhaa, Caruana, Abasov, Gujrathi, Nakamuru, Gukesh, and Firouzja.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2024 FIDE Candidates Tournament will be hosted by the [Great Hall](https://thegreathall.ca/) in Toronto, Ontario, Canada. According to the [tournament's official website](https://candidates2024.fide.com/), the media day and opening ceremony are on April 3 and the first round will be on the 4th. The final round will be on April 21 and tie breaks (if needed) and closing ceremony will be on April 22. [Tickets are available online](https://candidates-tournament-2024.square.site/).

An update: Unfortunately there now seems to be the possibility that the tournament will have to be moved to another country - probably Spain, as some players are having trouble obtaining visas. (I heard this on the [C-squared podcast](https://c2pod.com/). Visa Guide also has [an article](https://visaguide.world/news/candidates-chess-tournament-may-be-relocated-to-spain-due-to-visa-delays-by-canada/) about it.)

2nd update: The visa issues have been resolved, the tournament will take place in Toronto as scheduled, as written up in this [Chess.com article](https://www.chess.com/news/view/candidates-given-green-light-visa-issues-resolved).

Comment: NB: I'm not in any way affiliated with FIDE or the event. When I originally asked the question, I was hoping to go. Unfortunately, I'm not going to be able to do that now, but I wanted to share the information for anyone who does want to go.